# Targeting HTML 5 in a 4.01 site version

Tags: html, doctype, html4

Just wondering, what exactly could happen if a website isn't developed for HTML 5 (HTML 4.01 instead) but still it has declared all the standards like doctype and charset for HTML 5.
like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is written in such a way that it gracefully degrades instead of fatal erroring. There will be no issues, especially as the browsers implement all of the now deprecated tags anyway.